# Issue with Let's Enrypt certificates and auto renewal

Tags: lets-encrypt

I'm not able to renew my certificate with Let's Encrypt.

To renew my certificates I'm using the command : `certbot renew --dry-run`

My version of certbot : certbot 0.31.0
My version of UBUNTU : Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

**Error message :**

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
** DRY RUN: simulating 'certbot renew' close to cert expiry
**          (The test certificates below have not been saved.)

All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/**************/fullchain.pem (failure)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/**************/fullchain.pem (failure)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/**************/fullchain.pem (failure)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/**************/fullchain.pem (failure)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/**************/fullchain.pem (failure)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/**************/fullchain.pem (failure)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/**************/fullchain.pem (failure)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/**************/fullchain.pem (failure)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
sudo certbot renew
```